# How to use an escape sequence as the glue for implode()

Tags: php

I have this piece of PHP code.

```
$lines = preg_split('/\n/', $this->sqlString);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($lines); $i++) {
    $line = $lines[$i];
    $lines[$i] = $this->str_contains($line, '--') ? substr($line, 0, strpos($line, '--')) : $line;
}
$this->sqlString = trim(implode(' ', $lines));
```

What it does is take a SQL sentence and fully remove all the commentary (anything after '--'). It works, however, I'm forced to use ' ' as the glue because if I use '\n' to denote a newline, `implode()` will use it literally instead of seeing it as a newline. In other words, the `\n` character will be visible.

How would I go about imploding an array and using escape sequences as glue? Using the `<br>` tag is out of the question because it breaks other future tasks with the string.

Comment: Use `"\n"` instead of `'\n'`, In other words use double quotes instead of single quote.

Comment: The only escape sequences in single quoted strings are `\'` and ``\\``. https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: Try `PHP_EOL` constant as glue.

Comment: Both `"\n"` and `PHP_EOL` worked. Thanks, albeit odd.

Comment: Use "\n", single quotes use less escape sequences than double quotes do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy one, use double quotes to take newlines and special characters interpreted

```
$this->sqlString = trim(implode("\n", $lines));
```